# Why can't I connect to a local website remotely?

Tags: iis, mediawiki, windows-server-2008

I set up a web server (for media wiki, specifically) on a computer with a few other functional web sites.  I chose port `9191`. It works correctly from `localhost:9191`.

When I attempt to view the site from another computer, it redirects me to localhost and cant find it, as if I'm trying to connect to a computer that doesn't exist.

Any ideas?  Any other error codes I can look for?

I'm using Win-2008-R2/IIS.

Comment: Unless you have done so already, you need to configure your router or gateway to redirect the right port through. If you already did that, we need more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you're being redirected to "localhost", that means you might not be using the [private network IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and port number of the host computer (e.g., `192.168.1.1:9191`) if on the same network, or its [public IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_addresses) and port if on a different network (e.g., `74.125.225.101:9191`).

Another possibility is that you have JavaScript, VBScript, meta refresh, or another redirect in the default page that's redirecting to "localhost" instead of the IP address of the host computer. Sometimes developers will have web servers running on their development/test computers, so make sure there isn't an IIS or Apache service running on them too.

On Windows it's also important to make sure that there's an [exception in Windows firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751530.aspx) for IIS for port `9191`, as well as unblocking port `9191` in any other firewall or router between you and the host computer (though you wouldn't even get the localhost page if these were the case, unless you were viewing browser cache somehow).

Lastly, since you're able to reach the content on the same computer, you likely already changed the port of IIS to serve your site on port `9191`. If not, here's how: [Microsoft Support - How to change the TCP port for IIS services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605).

Comment: @glutz Was my answer helpful?